# Storing jquery clone elements to window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built a page [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XpAk5), Now I want to store the values entered in the input to `window.localStorage`. Please help me doing the same.

Comment: it looks like two new inputs are created when you click add item button, do you want to store all the added items to localStorage?

Comment: **code** yes thank you

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` can only store strings. Because you want to store all the items added to `localStorage` you will have to make a string from your list and every time, get the existing list, append, and then re-stringify. Inside your `addItem` click function

```
var names = localStorage.getItem('name');
var descriptions = localStorage.getItem('description');
if (names == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify([$('.item:last input[name*="-name"]').val()]));
    localStorage.setItem('description', JSON.stringify([$('.item:last input[name*="-description"]').val()]));
} else {
    names = JSON.parse(names);
    descriptions = JSON.parse(descriptions);
    names.push($('.item:last input[name*="-name"]').val());
    descriptions.push($('.item:last input[name*="-description"]').val());
    localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(names));
    localStorage.setItem('description', JSON.stringify(descriptions));
}
```

`JSON.stringify` will make your list into a string to put into storage, and `JSON.parse` will create a list from your string from storage so you can edit the list.